# Перебор строк json с интервалом

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, javascript

Есть такой код:

```
function get_frame(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/zone_moves.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action:"get_frame"},
        success: function(resp) {
            $.each(resp, function(){
                $("div#3_4").text(this.text)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Суть его такова. Получаем двумерный json массив с сервера. В каждом волженном массиве есть поле "text". Подскажите, как, допустим с промежутком в 5 секунд отображать это поле, допустим в алерт или как в коде в div'e. Т.е. ответ получен, показали значение поля text первой строки массива в диве, через 5 секунд следующая строка и т.д. Пока массив не закончится. А как закончится, нужно снова получить новые данные с сервера.

Т.е. на данный момент код как бы работает (без повторного опроса, но это не проблема), но пробегается он по строкам массива так быстро, что визуально это не видно и выглядит, как-будто в диве отображается только последняя строка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно как-нибуь так:

```
function get_frame(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/zone_moves.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action:"get_frame"},
        success: function(resp) {
            var i = 0;
            for(var pd in resp){  // перебираем свойства объекта
                (function(){  // создаём пространство имён для сохранения i и pd внутри таймаута
                    var p = i,
                        d = pd;
                    setTimeout(function(){  // устанавливаем паузы между сменами
                        $("div#3_4").text(resp[d].text)
                    }, 5000 * p);
                })();
                i++;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                get_frame();  // получаем новую порцию данных с сервера
            }, 5000 * i);
        }
    })
}
```

а вообще у тебя проблема в том что ты забыл установить интервал, и поэтому у тебя $.each моментально пробегается по json-у и также быстро меняет значения в диве

Comment: >а вообще у тебя проблема в том что ты забыл установить интервал, и поэтому у тебя $.each моментально пробегается по json-у и также быстро меняет значения в диве

Эта проблема и есть суть вопроса =)

Comment: что-то я спросоня подтупливаю, ну если скопировать код success-а, то должно заработать

Comment: Да, спасибо, работает. Но неужели нет более "элегантного решения"?

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать `setInterval` и замыкание:

```
function get_frame(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/zone_moves.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action:"get_frame"},
        success: function(resp) {
            // если нужно можно сделать resp.reverse
            var intervalId;
            var closure = function () {
                if (resp.length == 0) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    get_frame();
                    return;
                }
                var elt = resp.pop();
                $("div#3_4").text(elt.text);
            };
            intervalId = setInterval(closure, 5000);
        }
    });
```

Нет возможности проверить, но должно работать.

Comment: Да, работает, благодарю. А вот что нужно поправить, чтоб небыло паузы перед показом 1-го элемента массива? А то получается после получения данных тоже приходится ждать 5 секунд до появления 1-го элемента.

Comment: я не знаю что это за пауза.
Хм. там после `get_frame()` должен быть `return`

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.prototype.iterateTimeout = function(timeout, action, done) {
  done = done !== undefined ? done : function(){};
  var arr = this;
  for( var i=0, l=arr.length, last=l-1; i<l; ++i ) {
    (function( i ){
      setTimeout(function() {
         action( arr[i] );
         if(i === last) {
           done();
         }
      }, i*timeout)
    }( i ))
  }
}
```

Пример:

```
 ([1,2,3,4,5]).iterateTimeout(500, 
                                function(v){ console.log(v) },
                                function(){console.log("completed")}
                             );
```

Пример зацикливания:

```
function foreverIterateTimeoutExample(){
 ([1,2,3,4,5]).iterateTimeout(500, function(v){ console.log(v) }, foreverIterateTimeoutExample)
}
foreverIterateTimeoutExample();
```

И того:

```
function get_frame(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/zone_moves.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action:"get_frame"},
        success: function(resp) {
            resp.iterateTimeout(5000, function(text){
            $("div#3_4").text(text)
        }, get_frame)
    })
}
```

Если перед вызовом callback'a тоже нужен таймаут - допишите сами. Причем лучше тогда в самом параметре `done`, как-то так:

```
 success: function(resp) {
    resp.iterateTimeout(5000, function(text){
      $("div#3_4").text(text)
 }, function() {
     setTimeout(get_frame, 5000);
 })
```

Последний коммент улыбнул, ок, для особо разбирающихся - без прототипа:

```
 var iterateTimeout = function( arr, timeout, action, done) {
  done = done !== undefined ? done : function(){};
  for( var i=0, l=arr.length, last=l-1; i<l; ++i ) {
    (function( i ){
      setTimeout(function() {
         action( arr[i] );
         if(i === last) {
           done();
         }
      }, i*timeout)
    }( i ))
  }
 }

iterateTimeout([1,2,3,4,5], 500, function(v){console.log(v)}, function(){console.log("done")})

function get_frame(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/zone_moves.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {action:"get_frame"},
        success: function(resp) {
            iterateTimeout(resp, 5000, function(text){
            $("div#3_4").text(text)
        }, get_frame)
    })
}
```

PS: учите язык, то что вы написали ужасно О_О

Comment: Спасибо, но prototype не используется

Comment: > PS: учите язык, то что вы написали ужасно О_О

И что же там ужасного?

> для особо разбирающихся - без прототипа

Вы всегда такой "умник"? Дерзость аж прет от вас

Comment: @DemoS - я не о вашем коде, а о "prototype не используется". Вы сравните прототипную функцию от не прототипной, много отличий видите? Особенно в логике ;D. ИМХО - любой адекватный джун переписал бы функцию с легкостью и понял-бы что прототип сдесь используется для красоты и лаконичности. Еще вопросы?

@DemoS - когда человек не знает элементарных вещей и, вместо того что-бы молча разобраться - пишет что не канает, не знаю, не умею и т.д. писать по другому не считаю целесообразным.

Comment: @AlexWindHope. Ну на счет красоты я бы поспорил! Ибо первые два ответа (ИМХО) гораздо аккуратнее, понятнее, красивее и проще.

> когда человек не знает элементарных вещей и, вместо того что-бы молча разобраться - пишет что не канает, не знаю, не умею и т.д. писать по другому не считаю целесообразным.

1. А смысл этого сайта тогда, если все будут сами разбираться???
2. В метках топика prototype нету. Потому ваш ответ скорее считается "не целесообразным"

Comment: Прототипы это нативная часть языка JavaScript, данный пример не имеет **абсолютно никакого отношения к библиотеке prototype**
Eсли вы о них ничего не знаете о прототипах - виноват в этом не я.

Первые два ответа решают задачу локально, я же привел пример решения задачи глобально. Первый метод это практически мой ответ, за исключением того что в нем код пишется "в лоб". Во втором ответе, попросту, применяется абсолютно иной подход.

Ага давайте теперь в метках топика перечислять все возможности языка... Улыбнуло :D